# Pagination of code igniter on index function

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i want to put pagination on my page, it works on links 2,3,4 and so on. But everytime i click the first and 1 the page shows me access forbidden, the link that first and 1 give me is "palmydentist/admin/dentist/index/". I think the problem is /index/ but i dont know how to fix it. If i click other link for example 2 the "palmydentist/admin/dentist/index/2/" it gives me no error.

here is my code in controller

```
class dentist_list extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('Admin_model', 'Admin');
        $this->load->library("pagination");

    }

    public function index($uri_segment="4")
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('admin_id'))
        {
            $data = array();
            $config = array();

            $config['base_url'] = base_url() . "admin/dentist_list/index/";
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->Admin->record_count();
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;

            $data["patient"] = $this->Admin->dentist_list($config["per_page"], $page);
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

            $data['table_data'] = $data['patient']['td'];

            $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('dentist_dashboard/footer','', true);
            $this->load->view('admin/dentist_list', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location: ' . base_url() . 'admin');
        }
    }
}
```

dont mind the model...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "admin/dentist_list/index/";
```

To,

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . "dentist_list/index/";
$config['uri_segment'] = 3;
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You give an argument `$uri_segment="4"`to the `index`function which assumes your url structure always has a `$uri_segment` (it doesn't in the case of 1), plus you don't use that argument further down your code. You could just go:

```
public function index()
```

Answer (score 0):

This sentence look rare..

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

- When you access to 'admin/dentist_list/index/' the 3rd segment is 'index' so $page = '' (probably this fail)
- when you access to 'admin/dentist_list/' the 3rd segment is empty so $page = 0;

So why not check for the 4th segment only?

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 1; // I don't know how you paginate the query in you model but the first page is 1
```

By the way the $uri_segment argument seems to be obsolete.

PD: I'm argentinian and my english skill are a little poor..